# Left join - nvarchar/bigint

Tags: sql-server, nvarchar, bigint

I'm in the last stages of building a report and I've run into this error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

I suspect this is to do with the LEFT JOIN i am using, I am just trying to get the Label field from this table, nothing else.

```
  LEFT JOIN [taxonomies_taxonomy_entry]
  ON [era_account_details].[sector] = [taxonomies_taxonomy_entry].[taxonomyentryid]

 [taxonomies_taxonomy_entry].[label] AS [Industry]
```

I am trying to select out the label field which is a nvarchar field.

The LEFT JOIN uses: 
[era_account_details].[sector] = nvarchar 
[taxonomies_taxonomy_entry].[taxonomyentryid] = bigint

Any advice?

Many thanks,

Comment: Why are they different types?

Comment: I have no idea; I didn't design the database :(

Comment: You'll have to convert one type to another with a `CAST` or `CONVERT`. This will prevent the optimizer from using any indexes though. This will be a *slow* query. If `sector` is supposed to contain *only* integer values (and doesn't contain any junk), you could convert it to `bigint`. Another option would be to add an indexed `nvarchar` column to `taxonomies_taxonomy_entry` with the string representation of the Id. Still ugly but you wouldn't have to update any existing data

Comment: Thanks for your advice Panagiotis, The amount records picked up by this query in particular is 2751 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could this do the trick?

```
CAST([taxonomies_taxonomy_entry].[taxonomyentryid]  As nvarchar(500))
```

Comment: EPIC JUST FIGURED IT OUT!

Comment: Note that this is an operation around a column/value, so this makes it rather expensive. But if you're not allowed to change the database, this is pretty much all you can do.